# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'subject' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: laravel-5, controller

I am trying to get result for specific subject, test and student but i am having the above error so far i had tried this thing and got the above error.

```
 $result = DB::table('results')
    ->where([
        ['subject',$request->subject],
        ['test',$request->test],
        ['user_id',$request->name]
    ])
     ->join('users','results.user_id','=','users.name')
    ->join('tests','tests.id','=','results.test')
    ->join('subjects','subjects.id','=','results.subject')
    ->select('results.*','users.name','tests.test_name','subjects.subjects')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the `subjects` and `results` tables have a column called `results`, so the MySQL error is telling you that the database is unsure as to which one you want to select.  You may try:

```
->where([
    ['subjects.subject', $request->subject],
    ['test', $request->test],
    ['user_id', $request->name]
])
```

Note that this same problem exists in your select clause.  You might want to alias `subjects.subjects` as something else, e.g.

```
->select('results.*', 'users.name', 'tests.test_name',
         'subjects.subjects AS s_subjects')
```

Comment: thanks for your time but i have column  in results as 'user_id','test','subject' and in datatable  i want to get the 'test_name' which is saved in 'tests' table, 'Student name' saved in 'users' and 'subject name' in table 'subjects' in column 'subjects' now tell me what is the best way to get this data..

Comment: That's a different question.  It is not what you asked above.

Comment: in the end thats what i want to get actually.

Comment: Great.  Then you may open another question.

Comment: well it will take 90 minutes to post another question. guide me here plz